# Toolkits for compiling into a custom machine language

Tags: assembly, virtual-machine, machine-code

lets say i built an interpreter (more like a virtual machine) capable of running a selection of basic commands. Naturally, i dont want to use a Hex-Editor to build the machine code (which is totally made up and not similar to any other architecture) by hand.

Are there any pre-existing tools for such situations?
I was thinking like using some tool to compile some high-level language like C into a basic assembler syntax, but at the same time restrict the compiler to using only a selection of asm commands (like only basic mov, alu commands, push/pop, calls and jump).

Of course one option is to build a whole new compiler for that from scratch, but that obviously sucks and feels like reinventing the wheel.
Another option would be to write a script working on the generated asm code, replacing the not-supported commands with others (like splitting lea into mov and arithmetrics), but that would be quite some work with more complicated commands.
I would like to cut my own work down to writing an assembler at max, preferable one which only gets a selected subset of commands (so none of these fancy complicated x86 commands like ascii/bcd arithmetics, xchng, string commands or even lea) to simplify things.
Would that even be a feasible approach, or is there an easier way to achieve what i want?
I am sure i am not the first one doing something like this.
Ideally, i would need a compiler where i can describe the target architecture and its capabilities in detail.

Does anyone have done something similar before? I don't even really know where to start, but surely there must be some tools available helping with this.

**Edit:**
To make it clear, i am indeed looking for tools to build bytecode for a self defined ISA. I mentioned C as a high-level language, but that was just an example. I am just looking for a way to program simple snippets for a custom-defined architecture without writing the bytecodes by hand in an hex editor, preferably with a higher-level language. My idea was just, that if i could minimise the instruction set assumed by some standard compiler, i could write some simple script to just translate it into my custom machine code.

Comment: GCC is designed to be portable to new ISAs.  You'd need to write machine-definition files to tell the compiler what instructions exist, and probably manually implement some peephole optimizations to look for.

Comment: Your question is *very unclear*: are you implementing a new programming language, a new [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) or are you inventing a new [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) and trying to get a C compiler for it? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54054410/edit) your question to improve it a lot!

Comment: Normally for a new ISA, the first thing anyone writes is an *assembler*, like GAS or NASM, which can read asm source lines and assemble bytes of machine code to an output file.  Each line is independent.  Then you can have a compiler like gcc target that asm if you want to compiler higher level languages.  Like gcc, the GNU assembler (part of the binutils package) is designed to be portable, so you can probably use a lot of its source-parsing code and just add the things that are truly specific to your ISA.  But you might rather start with a simpler framework or write your own assembler.

Comment: I don't think translating from another ISA makes much sense; Probably too many idiosyncrasies even for nice orthogonal / simple ISAs like MIPS.

Comment: Even with the edit your question stays unclear. I don't understand what "build bytecode for a self defined ISA" means to you. (What is the bytecode in that sentence) Once you have defined an ISA, writing some assembler program for it is really easy.

Comment: Is your (even incomplete) project free software? Then give its URL please in your question (which stays *very confusing*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use some [JIT-compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library. There are lots of them, at least on Linux: [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [LLVM](https://llvm.org/), [libJIT](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), GNU [lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), etc... Both *libgccjit* and *LLVM* are capable of fancy optimizations.

<sup>(I first understood that you want to make a new compiler or JIT [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) interpreter for your existing PC under x86-64)</sup>

> Ideally, i would need a compiler where i can describe the target architecture and its capabilities in detail.

You could be interested by [iburg](https://github.com/drh/iburg) (and also, by some internals in GCC and/or Clang/LLVM).

If indeed you are inventing a new [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) (perhaps as some low-level [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode)), you could adapt and port [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) to it (write a new [machine-description](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/intdocs/gcc-writing-md.html) file, etc...). That could take you a few months of work. Ask help on `gcc@gcc.gnu.org`. Read the [GCC internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/) documentation. Be aware of [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html).

If you want a naive, **non-[optimizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)** C compiler (or for a C subset) for your new bytecode, you could take inspiration from [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) which shows that writing a *naive* C-like compiler from scratch is feasible quite easily (and might take less time than diving into [GCC internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/)). But that compiler won't optimize at all ! See [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065).

You also should consider compiling your language to C (and leave low level optimization and code generation to the system C compiler). This is a [quite popular approach](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065).

Notice also that **once you have completely specified an ISA, writing an assembler for it is a simple exercise** (and once you've got an assembler, you don't need to fiddle with bits in hexadecimal to write some code for your ISA).

You may be interested by [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) or [multi-stage programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_programming) languages. Look into Lisp -notably Common Lisp and its [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) implementation- and into MetaOcaml.

---

### your question is unclear

(even with the new edit)

Are you inventing a new bytecode, a new programming language, a new ISA ?

You need to read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and [The Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) to at least get the good terminology and concepts (since in its initial form your question is unclear and confusing). You should also be interested by Scott's [*Programming Language Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) and probably Queinnec's [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces).

---

> My idea was just, that if i could minimize the instruction set assumed by some standard compiler, i could write some simple script to just translate it into my custom machine code.

That is probably false. Some [one instruction set computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer)s have been invented, but in practice these 1-instruction set are not efficient to implement, so minimizing the instruction set to 1 is not a good idea. And using such a "one instruction set ISA" as an intermediate representation (in your compiler) is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of re-targettable (open source) compilers.  Gcc, llvm, and many others.  You will find that gcc is barely held together with duct tape and bailing wire, massive PITA.  llvm advertises ease of adding a backend and documentation but the documentation is so out of date that it is as misleading and wrong as it is helpful.  And the msp430 backend they used to demonstrate how easy.  that backend is broken and always has been and no desire to fix it...

Despite that it is certainly possible, backends are added every now and again. pdp-11 to gnu and risc-v to both gnu and llvm in recent years.  aarch64 and others.  Some folks will fork off a specific version of gcc or llvm and work to that, as it is one task to add one backend to one version of these tools, if you want to upstream it you would need to maintain it every version forever (or convince someone else to).

vbcc is another one I know about there are a number of others, optimizing and not.  You could go down the roll your own path of course.  Do you want/need a full blown compatible language like C or make your own subset.

if optimization is not required then you can possibly port existing backends, there is one in gcc that is basically a stack machine, you can port or make a static binary translation tool from it.  JAVA is a stack based there have been some attempts to do the same with that...old pascal compilers generated something like that tcc or one of his worked like that.

lcc is a textbook based one, non-optimizing...

Unfortunately none of the major compilers are designed to make backends easy with a tool.  You are the tool and have to do the work to get it shoved in there, ride that bear and hope that it works...

You can try approaching the individuals that did something similar to what you are doing the cris backend or the moxie backend, since those were completed and upstreamed they may have some advice...